# NSXMLParser not adding objects

Tags: iphone, ios, nsxmlparser

I'm new to the NSXMLParser, so I decided to take this tutorial: http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/parsing-xml-files/ and it was great. But in my app I used parser not in AppDelegate, but in other ViewController. I changed initialization to this:

```
-(XMLParser *)initXMLParser {
    [super  init];

    viewController = (ViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    return self;
}
```

The parser itself works well but it doesn't add any objects to the array in view controller in which the objects should be added. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code call still your app delegate

Try with this kind of code

```
@interface XMLParser : NSObject {
    NSMutableString *currentElementValue;
    id<NSXMLPArserDelegate> delegate;
    Book *aBook;
}
-(XMLParser *)initXMLParserWithDelegate:(id<NSXMLPArserDelegate>) delegate;
@end;


-(XMLParser *)initXMLParserWithDelegate:(id<NSXMLPArserDelegate>) _delegate {
    self = [super  init];
    if(self) {
        delegate = _delegate;
    }
    return self;
}
```

And set the delegate with self in your constructor

Comment: Should I do this in ViewController.h: @interface FirstLevelViewController : UITableViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>?

Comment: yes in the FirstLevelViewController you have to do do something like XMLParser* parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParserWithDelegate:self];

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe I should change some code inside parser methods?