# I'm parsing XML and have warning

Tags: iphone, xml, nsxmlparser

Here is my code in appdelegate.m

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:kBioXML];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc]initXMLParser];
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];     < - warning
```

XMLParser.h looks like

```
@class AppDelegate, Bio;

@interface XMLParser : NSObject {
NSMutableString *currentElementValue;

AppDelegate *appDelegate;
Bio *aBio;

NSString * bioText;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *bioText;
- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser;
@end
```

And XMLParser.m

```
@implementation XMLParser

@synthesize bioText;

- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser{
[super init];
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
bioText = @"";
return self;
}
```

The warning is "Sending XMLParser *" to parametr of incompatible type 'id
what i should change to solve this warning?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this instead of your method..

```
-(id) initXMLParser
{
    self = [super init];
    if( self != nil )
    {
         appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
         bioText = @"";
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Update**

Implement NSXMLParserDelegate like this

In you .h file replace `@interface XMLParser : NSObject` with `@interface XMLParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>` got it?

Comment: the same warning ... 'id<NSXMLParserDelegate>'

Comment: do you mean NSXMLParserDelegate * par = [NSXMLParserDelegate alloc] init]; ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use NSXMLParserDelegate object instead of nsxml parser and NSXMLParserDelegate protocol defines the optional methods implemented by delegates of NSXMLParser objects.

I hope it may help you !!!

Comment: You can try in this way                                 NSXMLParser  *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

 XMLParserdelegate *parserdeleagte = [[XMLParserdelegate alloc] init];
 [xmlParser setDelegate:parserdelegate];

[xmlParser parse];

Comment: I mean to say in this way check this question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245407/trouble-with-nsxmlparser-example-please-help

Answer (score 2):

Your XMLParser class does not implement the NSXMLParserDelegate interface

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html